# Invalid script entry point, A callable suffix is required

Tags: rhel, pip, python3

I'm trying to install [btrfs-sxbackup](https://github.com/masc3d/btrfs-sxbackup) on `RHEL7`. It says:

> Installation: pip install btrfs-sxbackup
>
> Required: python3

I installed `python34` from epel. There's no `pip` for it, so I installed it, like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771094/447503

`pip3` builds my package, but can't install it:

```
[root@wc8rh7 ~]# yum -y install python34
[root@wc8rh7 ~]# curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.4
[root@wc8rh7 ~]# pip3 install btrfs-sxbackup
Collecting btrfs-sxbackup
  Downloading btrfs-sxbackup-0.5.9.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: btrfs-sxbackup
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for btrfs-sxbackup ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/42/28/92/3f60b95db806b9d2e1b3a1a91acdac263dadfaba17a88b1df9
Successfully built btrfs-sxbackup
Installing collected packages: btrfs-sxbackup
Invalid script entry point: <ExportEntry btrfs-sxbackup = btrfs_sxbackup.__main__:None []> for req: btrfs-sxbackup - A callable suffix is required. Cf https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#console-scripts for more information.
```